# Is this scenario of dual submission possible?

Tags: conference

It is in computer science area.

The author notification date(notify people whether their paper get accepted) for conference A is 4 days later than the submission date of conference B.

Is that possible to submit it to both A and B?
If I get accepted to conference A, I will revoke my submission from conference B. Since it is only 4 days since the submission date of conference B, it is probably still in the paper bidding phase while no reviewers have read the full paper yet.

Comment: It's not considered good manners, I think, to play a game like this. It's "possible", as in your question, but might give you a bad reputation in some peoples' minds.

Comment: I have seen some CS conferences explicitly have a provision for this exact scenario in their submission instructions, when two popular conferences in the same (or closely related) field had such a (small) overlap in their timelines. In all other cases, I expect this would not be allowed.

Comment: It would certainly be okay to ask the program committee chair for Conference B if this could be allowed.  They may very well say yes.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo Thanks for you advice, I will send emails to the program committee chair for Conference B to ask about it..

Comment: You can also ask the program chair if it is possible to get a decision prior to the deadline of the second conference. Say why. There is a chance of a positive outcome, though it may be small. There is also the possibility that the submission deadline for the second will be extended as has happened lately. Especially when they don't get enough submissions to make them happy as the deadline approaches.

Comment: @Buffy Thanks for your advice.